# How to compress a directory with the built in .net compression classes?

Tags: .net, compression

Using the System.IO.Compression namespaces classes GZIPStream and DeflateStream I successfully can compress and decompress individual files. However, if I pass a directoryname as target for compression I get a security exception. Do I have to (recursively) enumerate all files and subdirectories to be able to compress a directory?

(Probably dotnetzip from codeplex will handle this better, but that is not what I am after now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `GZipStream` etc, you are compressing a **stream**; not a file. `GZip` has no file header information, so there is no sensible way of packing multiple files. For that you need something like .zip; #ziplib will do the job, but you still (IIRC) need to feed it each file manually.

Answer (score 4):

The `System.IO.Compression` classes provide no way to manage multifile archives. You need to do some work on your own to create a file format that track what is in your archive. This article might help you get started:

[How to compress folders and multiple files with GZipStream and C# (System.IO.Compression.GZipStream)](http://www.vwd-cms.com/Forum/Forums.aspx?topic=18)

However if you're after a format that you can exchange files with users who only have WinZip or WinRAR then you're better off looking into something like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

Answer (score 3):

The classes in System.IO.Compression will only handle streams, yes.  You'll have to do file handling yourself.  You could, I suppose, use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) or similar to tar the files, then compress the resulting tar file.  Simple as (untested):

```
using (Stream out = new FileStream("out.tar", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    TarArchive archive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(outStream
                                    , TarBuffer.DefaultBlockFactor);
    foreach (string name in fileNames)
    {
        TarEntry entry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(name);
        archive.WriteEntry(entry, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

People have mentioned this before, the built in .Net classes are good a compressing streams not directory structures.

They also mentioned that sharpziplib etc.. are good libraries to use, I agree. They offer Zip and Tar implementaions which are useful.

But... if your hands are tied and you can not use these libs, keep in mind that the [tar format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)) is really simple. Implementing:
`Stream ToTar(string path`) is a fairly simple and straight forward task (unlike implementing compression algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

This compresses .\in contents to .\out.zip with Powershell and System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage following the example [here](http://www.winsoft.se/2010/12/easy-archiving-of-files-using-powershell/)

```
$zipArchive = $pwd.path + "\out.zip"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("WindowsBase,Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
$ZipPackage=[System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage]::Open($zipArchive, [System.IO.FileMode]"OpenOrCreate", [System.IO.FileAccess]"ReadWrite")
$in = gci .\in | select -expand fullName
[array]$files = $in -replace "C:","" -replace "\\","/"
ForEach ($file In $files) {
   $partName=New-Object System.Uri($file, [System.UriKind]"Relative")
   $part=$ZipPackage.CreatePart($partName, "application/zip", [System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption]"Maximum")
   $bytes=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
   $stream=$part.GetStream()
   $stream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
   $stream.Close()
                                                    }
$ZipPackage.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the directory in pure .NET 3.0.

First, you will need a reference to WindowsBase.dll.

This code will open or create a zip file, create a directory inside, and place the file in that directory. If you want to zip a folder, possibly containing sub-directories, you could loop through the files in the directory and call this method for each file. Then, you could depth-first search the sub-directories for files, call the method for each of those and pass in the path to create that hierarchy within the zip file.

```
public void AddFileToZip(string zipFilename, string fileToAdd, string destDir)
{
    using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        string destFilename = "." + destDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileToAdd);
        Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(destFilename, UriKind.Relative));
        if (zip.PartExists(uri))
        {
            zip.DeletePart(uri);
        }
        PackagePart part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", CompressionOption.Normal);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToAdd, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
            {
                CopyStream(fileStream, dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

destDir could be an empty string, which would place the file directly in the zip.

Sources:
https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib

https://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/creating-a-folder-inside-the-zip-file-with-system-io-packaging