# Compress a file with GZipStream while maintaining its meta-data

Tags: c#, .net, compression

How can I get the extension of compressed file after being compressed with `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream`?

For example, if the original file is named `test.doc` and compresses to `test.gz`, how do I know what file extension to use when decompressing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this some time ago.  The solution is to use the J# libraries to do it.  You still write it in C# however.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx

That's microsofts answer on the topic.

Comment: Personally I'd rather use a library like SharpZipLib (http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) and stick to C#

Comment: There are times when it's not possible to use open source in closed source development.  This may not be the case but offers a solution from within the existing Microsoft SDK.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get the file name - in fact there may never be a filename at all, if for example a piece of data is created in memory and then send over a network connection.

Instead of replacing the file extension, why not append it, for example: test.doc.gz
Then you can simply strip it off when decompressing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your question- I assume you want a mechanism to "remember" what the extension was before the compression took place?

If that is the question then the convention of test.doc compressing into test.doc.gz will work.

Answer (score 0):

The test.gz is just a raw byte stream with no meta-data about what has been compressed (for example, original file name, extension etc). What you'd need to do is create an archive that contains the gzip stream and meta-data about each file contained in the archive.

The article linked to in [Mech Software's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001711/gzipstream-in-c-net/1001735#1001735) provides a pretty reasonable way to implement this.

There was also this question (vaguely related) asked some time back which may help out:

> [How to compress a directory with the built in .net compression classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900031/how-to-compress-a-directory-with-the-built-in-net-compression-classes)